# Can I remove my lemon tree when it has fruit but is not growing well in a corner of the garden?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, citrus, lemons

I transplanted my lemon tree from a pot to the corner garden bed. Since then, it has a lot of flowers and has lots of lemons.
It is only just over a meter high but seems to be stagnated now, as the fruit has been the same size for a couple of months.
I water and feed it, but the fruit seems more like limes than the huge lemons it previously produced.

Comment: Good question; if could include an illustration & close illustration of leaves, the variety name of your Lemon Tree, current watering amount & frequency, how long it has been transplanted, soil type, previous nutrient type & amount and frequency, current nutrient type & amount and frequency, if there has been change in the typical daytime temperature and/or typical night time temperature, and if a change in amount & intensity of sun, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: What part of the world are you in - this is very important to know? When did the fruits first start growing this year? Is it in a sunny position?

Answer (score 3):

Soil for citrus trees should be slightly acid, not alkaline, but above all should be well drained. They don't like to have their feet wet, so if there is a risk that when you water the tree the water will sit around and flood the roots then the tree will demonstrate its unhappiness by not growing or shedding leaves. Quite possibly when you moved the tree from a well drained pot to a less well drained garden location you continued to water it as if it was still in the pot and consequently gave it more water than the soil was capable of dealing with. You can test this by driving a stick into the soil close to the tree and then pulling the stickout to leave a deep narrow hole, then use a dipstick to see how far down the water table is. Standing water at the bottom of the hole is a problem for the tree, which should be moved to a higher spot or watered much less frequently - whatever allows the roots to grow freely into soil which always has some water with lots of air.

Comment: Excellent & interesting answer; also, even if the tree's roots are above the water table, the tree could still be receiving more water than optimal if the watering regimen has remained the same but the new location retains water more than the container did. Thank you